# synching postgresql database between two EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

When running (fictitious ip addresses) on an EC2 instance that is intended to be a slave postgresql database:

```
ubuntu@ip-127-31-71-50:/var/lib/postgresql/9.3$ sudo -u postgres pg_basebackup -h 54.419.311.274 -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main -U rep -v -P -x
```

The response is:

```
pg_basebackup: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "54.419.311.274" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Having run this command on non_AWS instances successfully, I wonder what configuration is required under AWS to make this run properly.
User postgres exists on the master as

```
sudo su postgres
```

allows editing postgre via its main user.

postgresql.conf on master EC2 instance has

```
listen_addresses = 'localhost,54.419.311.274,54.86.79.188'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: are your security groups properly configured?

Comment: I believe so, but stand to be corrected. On the master I created an inbound rule (with all ports for the public ip of the slave for testing purposes) and bound it to the instance: `All TCP TCP 0 - 65535  54.86.79.188/32`. Whereas on the slave (again trying things large) I created (and bound) `Custom TCP Rule TCP 5432 0.0.0.0/0`.  This is clearly a mishandling of AWS configuration, as I've tested this on another VPS successfully just now.

Comment: @tedder42 A thought. Should the security rules use the public IP or the private IP of the instance?

Comment: I almost posted that at first :) if you are connecting via the public IP that's the one to use. If you are using DNS or the private IP, that one. Can you ssh from A to B? I like the idea of binding to 0.0.0.0/0, certainly. Does it work?

Comment: @tedder42 I'm ssh'ing into the slave and then calling pg_basebackup from the master. So I created a security rule for just port 5432 than modified the command to call the private IP address `sudo -u postgres pg_basebackup -h 172.31.72.189 -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main -U rep -v -P -x` Sits there for a 5 minutes or so and times out `could not connect to server: Connection timed out` Time to look anew at the listen_addresses and leave the private one there?

Comment: okay, if you ssh to the slave, what happens when you ssh to the master? It doesn't really matter if you have keys, all we want to know is that the connection works.

Comment: permission is denied when using public ip or public DNS.  When ssh'ing with the private ip 5 minutes pause til timeout.

Comment: okay, that's proof you have something wrong on your security group for the master.

Comment: @tedder42 Amidst all attempts, I went as far as setting Inbound rule on master as 0.0.0.0/0 port 5432 in both TCP and UDP. No change in behaviour.